# Amazon AWS licensing model for windows

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

Folks,

I had a quick question about Amazon EC2, I have been recently using it for doing some data mining for scientific research(genetics). I do all my work on a Linux instance, but I also noticed that amazon lets you launch a windows instance there. I am just curious to know how does the licensing work for this, am I already paying for this as part of my AWS bill?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EC2 pricing includes your Windows licence fees, hence why they are more expensive than Linux instances.

Some instance types also include SQL Server licenses but you are free to use your own licenses if you have them.

Full details are on the [AWS EC2 pricing page](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/).